# How can I access this Handler from an HTML?

Tags: c#, html, handler

I want to access this Handler from a HTML form

```
public class Eventos : IHttpHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You will need to configure this handler in the Web.config file of your 
        /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
        /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
        /// </summary>
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
            // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //write your handler implementation here.
;

            string Tipo = context.Request.QueryString["Tipo"];

            switch (Tipo)
            {
                /*Pagina Index Portada Perfil -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
                case "IndexSelectPerfil":
                    {
                        RegistroEvento(context);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And this is how I want to call it on the HTML form

```
<form class="form-header" action="IX_Registros.Handlers.Eventos" role="form" method="POST" id="#">
```

But I just can't access it, and saw various pages saying to create an ashx file for the handler, but I don't see where to create it or use it
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and created it with the help of the Code On Time framework

Comment: Normally, with a web framework such as MVC, then it will route the action through to a controller for you based on your routes configuration. What framework are you using for this?

Comment: I am using Code On Time to generate the WebApp and some bootstrap for the style of the HTML

Comment: Never used that framework before, so I don't know how it handles URL routing, I'm afraid. You'll have to check their documentation to see how to route your URL pattern to your controller. You should update your question to include that you're using the Code On Time framework.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this guide http://codepedia.info/generic-handler-ashx-file-post-send-json-data-parameters-in-asp-net-c-jquery/ to access the handler and post JSON to my HTML page.